# Passing strings to another window using `WM_COPYDATA`

Tags: api, vb6, wm-copydata

am sending data using this code in vb6

```
cds.dwData = CLng(RegisterWindowMessage("MyWMCopyData"))
cds.cbData = Len(Message) * 2 ' characters are 2-bytes each
cds.lpData = StrPtr(Message) ' access the string's character buffer directly
' Send the string.
Dim i As Long:i = SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COPYDATA, MainForm.hwnd, cds)
```

can you help me with the code to receive it vurrently i have this

```
Dim B() As Byte
ReDim B(0 To tCDS.cbData - 1) As Byte
CopyMemory B(0), ByVal tCDS.lpData, tCDS.cbData
Dim sData As String
sData = Trim$(StrConv(B, vbUnicode))
```

if i send `Hello`, i get it as `H e l l o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up string conversions.

Your sending code sends a pointer to the full unicode string.
When you receive it, you then pass it to `StrConv(..., vbUnicode)` which converts from ANSI to unicode, "corrupting" the string data.

To resolve this, you just need to assign the final byte array directly to the string:

```
sData = B
```

Alternatively, you can allocate the string length and copy directly into it:

```
Dim sData As String  
sData = String(tCDS.cbData / 2, vbNullChar) ' characters are 2-bytes each
CopyMemory ByVal StrPtr(sData), ByVal tCDS.lpData, tCDS.cbData
```

Comment: may i ask why you are doing this `tCDS.cbData / 2`, i thought the unicode string will ocupy the original space as its 2 bytes per character

Comment: i get a type mismatched on this line `sData = String(vbNullChar, tCDS.cbData / 2)` so i swtch it like this `sData = String( tCDS.cbData / 2,vbNullChar)`

Comment: I divide by two for the same reason you multiply by two for sending it. `WM_COPYDATA` deals with bytes whereas the string length is in characters. Each character is two bytes. I've fixed the call to `String()` too.

Answer (score 0):

The string is in Unicode format

In uncode, each single character occupy 2 bytes, as ASCII was just 1 byte, so i think vb fill the another byte with white space (maybe)